# How to compare two points in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, compare, cgpoint

I have a `UITextView` which contains text and images. I also have a `CGPoint` array containing coordinates of images added by a user in the `UITextFied`. Whenever texts in the `UITextView` changes (addition or deletion), I get the position of the cursor which is a `CGPoint` object.

Now I want to loop through my `CGPoint` array to find how many images fall after the cursor position whether on the same line or lines below. How do I go about it?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Sure:

```
var cursor = message.caretRectForPosition(message.selectedTextRange?.end).origin;    
for i in 0...emoji1.count-1 {
        if ((cursor.x > emoji_pt[i].x)  && (cursor.y <= emoji_pt[i].y)) {
            continue;
        }
        else {
            //the emoji is after the cursor.
            // Return the index and process all images after that index
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please post your attempts and describe why they aren't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle the Y position

```
Bool onPreviousLine = (emoji_pt[i].y < cursor.y)
```

To handle the X position (`lineHeight` being a constant depending on your case and the size of images, you could probably get away with some low constant value (e.g. `1.0`)).

```
Bool onTheSameLine = abs(Double(emoji_pt[i].y - cursor.y)) < Double(lineHeight / 2)
Bool beforeX = (emoji_pt[i].x < cursor.x)
```

Together

```
if onPreviousLine || (onTheSameLine && beforeX) {
    continue
}
```

Comment: I tried that but I realized that, when there are about 3 lines of text and images and the cursor is on the last line, it moves all images which are "vertically behind" the x point.

Comment: @MichaelWoyo Edited the answer, forgot a case.

Comment: I will get back to you on the results I get. Thanks all the same.

Comment: please bear with me because am pretty new to iOS and Swift.
I tried your suggestion but I didn't know how to get the line height. I asked a friend and he said it's same as font size (in my case, 20). Dividing that by 2 yields 10. I however received this error `Cannot invoke < with argument list of CGFloat ....`

Comment: @MichaelWoyo I am writing from memory so there could be some type problems. Try it now.

Comment: it sure did work. Thanks a lot champ.

Sorry, I can't vote you up because my reputation is quite low but I salute you.